# SSRS Check if a parameter exists

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 reports, the main report and the summary report. The summary report is connected to the main report, which means that some parameters are passed to the summary report.

Now, if the user wants to view the summary report without opening the main report first, how to use an expression wherein it checks:

- If the [StartDate] parameter is existing, it will inherit the value of the
  [StartDate] parameter from the main report.
- If the [StartDate] parameter does not exist, it will have a default value.

This is what my expression looks like:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!StartDate.Value) = false,CDate(Parameters!StartDate.Value), switch (
Weekday(today) = 1, dateadd("d", -7, today),
Weekday(today) = 2, dateadd("d", -8, today),
Weekday(today) = 3, dateadd("d", -9, today),
Weekday(today) = 4, dateadd("d", -10, today),
Weekday(today) = 5, dateadd("d", -11, today),
Weekday(today) = 6, dateadd("d", -12, today),
Weekday(today) = 7, dateadd("d", -13, today)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your summary report, build a dataset that calculates the default StartDate in SQL, it will be similar to your current expression. Set the default values of the summary report to point to your new dataset and that's it. If no parameter is passed the default will be used. No need for any expressions. I hope that makes sense, if not let me know and I'll give a more detailed answer.